# Which API Should consider to communicate with the customer using whatsapp

Tags: java, spring, maven

We are planning to communicate with our customer through whatsapp so what will be the best api for the same , what i learned about Whatsapp business api is we can only communicate with users who will send message first we can not initiate  the conversation. is there any possible way to achieve the same ?

Comment: Someone has to ping to whatsapp number first then only you can initiate conversion. This is one way, another is you can broadcast to a particular user with a number using whatsapp api like how makemytrip.com sends whatsapp message after ticket booking.

Answer (score 1):

Chat API is a good service you should at least consider using. However, it's not free. Check it out:
https://chat-api.com/en/?lang=EN